# Recreate app icon on homepage

Tags: iphone

I don't use any Apple gear, so sorry I'm struggling to find answers, as I'm not quite sure how to phrase my question.

My wife had a banking app on her phone, but our son managed to delete the icon from home screen (where all the app icons are). If she uses the search, it lists, and if we go to the app store, it gives the option to "Open" (and not "install"). So we assume it's still installed.

How do I add this back so she can access it without having to search or open the App Store?

Edit: To add, it's an iPhone 5

Thanks

Comment: What version of iOS does her phone run at? or what Model iPhone does she have?

Comment: It's an iPhone 5 (Took me ages to work out how to find that out)

Comment: I'm assuming you double checked any folders and all of her pages? If it's definitely not there try a restart (hold power and home button until phone reboots). Also, when you tap the icon after searching does it open? What happens then?

Comment: I didn't even know there were folders. I found it in one of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching in Spotlight for an app will reveal its containing folder

[Source](http://www.cultofmac.com/201291/use-spotlight-on-your-iphone-or-ipad-to-find-apps-in-folders-ios-tips/)

Comment: I saw it said "Finance" next to it, but as I didn't realise there were folders, just thought this was a category description. Found and sorted now, thanks to everyone